# How can I push new elements inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the next object with this format, and I wanto to insert new objects inside the day:

```
var new_array = [ 
  {"sunday":[]}, 
  {"monday":[]}, 
  {"tuesday":[]},
  {"wednesday":[]},
  {"thursday":[]},
  {"friday":[]},
  {"saturday":[]} 
];
```

I use a loop for determinate the day and then insert the

```
for( let el of arr) {
        switch(el.activitie_day) {
            case 'sunday':
                new_array[0]["sunday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'monday':
                new_array[0]["monday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'tuesday':
                new_array[0]["tuesday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'wednesday':
                new_array[0]["wednesday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'thursday':
                new_array[0]["thursday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'friday':
                new_array[0]["friday"].push(el);
                break;
            case 'saturday':
                new_array[0]["saturday"].push(el);
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when I try this trows an error (Cannot read property 'push' of undefined).

Comment: Having an object of days would have been a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are always trying to push into the first element of the array.

```
new_array[0]["monday"].push(el);
```

This doesnt' exist. This should be.

```
new_array[1]["monday"].push(el);
```

Anyway, that code is not pretty. But that's another story

Comment: This is not the solution :(

Comment: Sure it is. That's what your array looks like.

Comment: No because new_array[0] is the first object then I can access to any key new_array[1,2,4... ] does not exist

Comment: Yes, you have the reason, I don't know what I was thinking :( Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up an **array** and **objects with properties**, in such a way that you have an array of items, each of which has a single property (item 0 has `sunday`, item 1 has `monday`, etc.)

A much better approach is by using an object with named properties, and matching the day names in `arr` with the property names in the target object (`itemsByDay`):

```js
var itemsByDay = {
  sunday: [],
  monday: [],
  tuesday: [],
  wednesday: [],
  thursday: [],
  friday: [],
  saturday: []
};
console.log(itemsByDay);

var arr = [];
arr.push({ activitie_day: 'tuesday', value: 1 });
arr.push({ activitie_day: 'friday' , value: 22 });
arr.push({ activitie_day: 'tuesday', value: 333 });

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var day = arr[i].activitie_day;
  // Check if day exists as property of itemsByDay, if so then add item to that array:
  if (itemsByDay[day])
    itemsByDay[day].push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(itemsByDay);
```

Comment: I was using the same object format but when I try to loop in Angular 4 using ngFor it throws the object is undefined :(

Comment: You can't easily loop an object, that is true. You could perhaps loop using a simple array `dayNames` and then use something like `itemsByDay[dayNames[i]]` or `itemsByDay[dayName]`.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of your switch-case condition. only `new_array[0]["sunday"]` does exist, therefor all other cases will result in `undefined`.

```
function modify(arr) {
  for( let el of arr) {
    if (el["monday"]) el["monday"].push("hello")
    if (el["tuesday"]) el["tuesday"].push("world")
     ......
  }
}

modify(new_array)
```